# PHP AJAX Registration form submission tutorial

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, authentication, user-registration

Can anyone please help me in finding good tutorials for php/jquery/ajax form submission validating each of the fields from the php code(server side validation). I have seen many tutorials on the web, but most of them show validating errors as a group. I want each of the error to be displayed next to the form field in the result. I have tried using php arrays to pass results into ajax using json... but its not working.

Any help will be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please post some code so we can actually see whats wrong and try to help you.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried and explain how it's not working?  If you have specific code which isn't doing what you expect it to do then we can be much more helpful with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using JSON, which is specially designed for AJAX.

On the server side:

```
$form_fields = array(); // Holds errors in the form
$form_fields['field1'] = true;
$form_fields['field2'] = 'Error bla bla';
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($form_fields);
```

and in javascript:

```
// put into "data" the response from the server
var responseObj = $.parseJSON(data);

// Check field1
if(responseObj.field1 === true) alert("Field1 is valid!");
else alert('Field1 is not valid: "'+responseObj.field1+'"!');

// Check field2
if(responseObj.field2 === true) alert("Field2 is valid!");
else alert('Field2 is not valid: "'+responseObj.field2+'"!');
```

You can build it however you like and you can add more values to the json object on the server side or structure it however you want.

The server side will make a string like:
{"field1":true,"field2":"Error bla bla"}

Which is practically javascript, and then on the javascript side the browser decodes the string into a javascript object.